# C# How can I make an extension accept IEnumerable instead of array for params

Tags: c#

Having this extension

```
    public static bool In<T>(this T t, params T[] values)
    {
        return values.Contains(t);
    }
```

wanted it to accept IEnumerable and casting to array if needed inside the extension, but I don't know how to use the params keyword for that.

Tryed :

```
    public static bool In<T>(this T t, params IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        return values.Contains(t);
    }
```

but this generates a compile-time error : **The parameter array must be a single dimensional array**

Is there any way to make the extension method support IEnumerable params ? if not, why not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible, as the error message very bluntly tells you.

It's not possible because the specs say it's not possible.  Microsoft has chosen to not implement the proposed feature, presumably because they never considered its benefits to be greater than its costs.

The best workaround you can manage is to create two overloads, one with `params`, and one accepting an `IEnumerable<T>`, and have one call the other (or, since your methods are so simple, just implement both):

```
public static bool In<T>(this T t, params T[] values)
{
    return In<T>(t, values.AsEnumerable());
}

public static bool In<T>(this T t, IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    return values.Contains(t);
}
```

Comment: See Python's `*args` for what he, probably, wants. :)

Answer (score 0):

`params IEnumerable` is not supported by the current version of C#. It is one of the requested features on Visual Studio UserVoice: [Allow using params IEnumerable](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2307928-allow-using-params-ienumerable-t-). You can upvote it.

This feature is [planned for C# 6](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated). When it is implemented, "The parameter array must be a single dimensional array" error message will go away.

Before that, you'll have to support two method overloads: one with an array, one with `IEnumerable`. See @Servy's answer.