# Confused as to why this C# code compiles, while similar code does not

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Let's take the following extension method:

```
static class Extensions
{
   public static bool In<T>(this T t, params T[] values)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

I'm curious as to why *this* code compiles and runs:

```
var x = new Object();
IEnumerable<int> p = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var t2 = x.In(p);
```

Within `In`, `values` is an `Object[]`, as if the `List<int>` gets converted on the fly to an array.  To me, it seems that `params T[]` does not match `IEnumerable<int>`, which is why I'm surprised this even runs.

Now this code:

```
var x = 5;
IEnumerable<int> p = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var t2 = x.In(p);
```

Does *not* run and generates the compiler error:

> Error 2   Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'int[]'

This is what I'd expect from the first one actually.  Can someone explain what's going on here?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking why the first one does compile or why the second one doesn't?

Comment: @SLaks - Was mostly wondering why the *first* one *does* compile, but your answer nailed it perfectly.

Comment: Then you should change your title. :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Type inference converts your first call to

```
In<object>(x, p);
```

The parameters of this closed generic method are `object, params object[]`.
Therefore, passing `p` implicitly converts it to an `object`, which becomes the single item in the params array.

Your second call is inferred (because of the first parameter) to

```
In<int>(x, p);
```

Here, the second parameter can either be an `int[]` (passing an array directly) or a series of `int`s (via `params`).
Since `IEnumerable<int>` is neither of those, you get an error.

Comment: Doh!  Totally missed the fact that `values` was an array of 1 item rather than 3 when I was debugging this, since hovering over it with the mouse automatically expands the values.  Had I seen this, I'd have gotten this right away!

Comment: @MikeChristensen Well, I [did explain that you you earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179175/c-sharp-how-can-i-make-an-extension-accept-ienumerable-instead-of-array-for-para/22179217?noredirect=1#comment33665841_22179218)...Granted, I explained it in code, not in words.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I didn't downvote your question.  It's not very mature to make such assumptions.  As for clarity, I assumed that you would be able to figure out the implications given the knowledge that the `IEnumerable` is wrapped in an array, [like you said you could have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180670/confused-as-to-why-this-c-sharp-code-does-not-compile/22180752?noredirect=1#comment33667209_22180752).

Comment: @MikeChristensen: OK now that you understand SLaks answer test your knowledge. You have `M(object)` and `M(params object[])`. You call `M(null);`  There are four possibilities. (1) error, (2) first method (3) second method with a null array (4) second method with a one-item array whose only item is null.  Which is it?

Comment: @EricLippert: To be fair, that's more about priorities in overload resolution, which I didn't discuss.

Comment: @EricLippert - Yea I agree with SLaks, seems to be an overload resolution priority issue.  I just gave it a shot, and looks like `M(params object[])` is called in this case, with the value being `null` (Option #3).  This, of course, begs the question of whether or not it's possible to disambiguate this call.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Use a cast.

Comment: @SLaks - What do you know, `1.In((Object)null);` will behave as per option #1.